# How to make so that, when running Activiti Modeller, in my application, the task and script task service after the timers do not cause errors?

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, activiti

If Activiti Modeler is running simultaneously with my application, and if it uses the same database for the Activiti engine as my application, then the service task and script task following the timers (the boundary timer event and the intermediate catching event) do not work, and cause errors. Error descriptions are as follows: "couldn't instantiate " - for the service task (if the class  is specified), "Can't find a scripting engine for 'groovy'" - for the script task. If I use Spring, and assign a bean to the service task, then I get an error with the description: "Could not execute service task expression".

At the same time I found and tried this recommendation:

> In order for everything to work without errors, you need to compile the classes that are used by the service task, and put them
>   with all the packages in which they are located in the *WEB_INF/classes* folder. Also, in order to avoid problems with the groovy, it is
>   necessary in *WEB_INF/lib* to throw the jar-file of this library, and
>   that used by the main program (the same version).

This works if Spring beans are not used. But this is also a crutch solution, and I would like to disable all event timer events in the database in Activiti Modeler. Not yet found how to do it.

I watched the documentation for the system administrator. It says about the properties that can be set in activiti-app.properties. I found several properties that, judging by the description, can help me, and tried to set the necessary values ​​for them:

```
elastic-search.server.type=none
event.processing.enabled=false
event.generation.enabled=false
```

But this also gave nothing.

Comment: It will be important if you share with us which version of Activiti are you using.

Comment: @salaboy I am using Activiti 6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

That is a limitation of running timers based on things that you are changing at runtime. We are fixing this in Activiti Cloud (Activiti 7) by separating the runtime in containers instead of just having a single monolithic application.

Comment: What solution do you offer?To use only Activiti Cloud (Activiti 7)? To shutdown the Activiti Modeler? Or anything else?

Comment: That limitation that you are hitting is one of the main reasons why we started Activiti Cloud. In Activiti Cloud Modeling and Runtime are separated and we use containers to publish and deploy new process versions to avoid class path clashing. If your current approach is giving you headaches yes, I would recommend to start looking into Activiti Cloud. It is really up to your use cases and your technology stack of choice. I do not offer solutions just alternatives.

Comment: Can I somehow disable the timers in the Activit Modeler (activiti-app)? I mainly use the Activit Modeler to work with the Activiti Administrator (activiti-admin) and to create bpm schemes, so i don't need firing timers in this app, and I can refuse it in this app.

Comment: But timers are triggered by the process engine which is running as part of the same app. You cannot disable that for parts of the application, if you disable it the engine will also get disabled.

Comment: Maybe you do not understand me. I wrote the separate app that uses the Activiti Engine сonnected as a library, and in may app I gave the database access to the Activiti engine. I registered the same database in the Activiti Modeler settings (the 'activiti-app.properties' file). In my application, I set the 'asyncExecutorActivate' flag by calling the 'setAsyncExecutorActivate' method (when creating the ProcessEngineConfiguration bean). Is it possible to turn off the same flag in Activiti Modeler?